# jQuery UI Droppable not working as expected on out: function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to reset the score of my div scrolling across the jQuery slider to 0 if it is returned to it's original position.

here is a plnk + some code;

https://plnkr.co/edit/oqhrDeP52vdzcKqpQvbl?p=preview

```
$(init);

function init() {

  function findPosition(e, ui) {
    var position = sliderDiv.position(),
      sliderWidth = sliderDiv.width(),
      minX = position.left,
      maxX = minX + sliderWidth,
      tickSize = sliderWidth / range;

    var finalMidPosition = ui.offset.left - 53 + Math.round($(divs).width() / 2 - 5)

    if (finalMidPosition >= minX && finalMidPosition <= maxX) {
      var val = Math.round((finalMidPosition - minX) / tickSize); 
      sliderDiv.slider("value", val);
      $(".slider-value", this).html(val);
      $("#text1").val($(".item1 .slider-value").html())

    }
  }

  var range = 100;
  var sliderDiv = $('#ratingBar');

  sliderDiv.slider({
    min: 0,
    max: range,
  });


  var divs = '.itemContainer'
  $(divs).draggable({
    containment: "#containment",
    cursor: 'move',
    snap: '#ratingBar',
    snapMode: 'outer',
    drag: findPosition,

    revert: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      };
      return !event;
    }
  });
  var position = sliderDiv.position(),
    sliderWidth = sliderDiv.width(),
    minX = position.left,
    maxX = minX + sliderWidth,
    tickSize = sliderWidth / range;
  $('#ratingBar').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: findPosition,
    out: function(event, ui) {
      $(".slider-value", ui.draggable).html(0);
      $("#text1").val($(".item1 .slider-value").html())

    }
  });
  $(".slider-value").html(sliderDiv.slider('value'));
}
```

I have had this working as expected in a different plnk, which leads me to believe that the issue is with either using the Drag: findPosition inside the Draggable or using `$(".slider-value", this).html(val);` instead of a variation of `$(".slider-value", ui.draggable).html(val);`.

Below, is a plnk which has the desired effect, but does not automatically update the value;

https://plnkr.co/edit/GIfq7Ws0EsjyS7yRhIzl?p=preview

Thanks for any help/advice!

Comment: Since `#containment` and `#ratingBar` do not overlap, you're draggable can never be `over` droppable, thus it is never `in`; therefore, cannot ever execute `out`. Unless I am misunderstanding the function here.

Comment: @Twisty Using this logic, if you set the barContainer bottom:0 then it should work? (I've tried, but it doesn't work)

Comment: no, I suspect moving `#ratingBar` inside of the `#containment` div, you could then have an interception between your drag item and the drop area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offer this as a solution. I made some minor HTML changes and then updated the jQuery.

My Fork: https://plnkr.co/edit/IPRoqprQt34Q08pugO9T?p=preview

**HTML**

```
  <div id="content">
    <div id="containment">
      <div id="itemArea">
        <div id="row">
          <div class="itemContainer">
            <div class="item1">
              <span class="slider-value"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="candle"></div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="barContainer">
          <div id="ratingBar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(init);

var over = false;

function init() {

  function findPosition(e, off) {
    if (e == "out") {
      over = false;
      sliderDiv.slider("value", 0);
      $(".slider-value").html(0);
      $("#text1").val(0);
      return;
    }
    if(e == "in"){
      over = true;
    }
    if (over && e == "drag") {
      var position = sliderDiv.position(),
        sliderWidth = sliderDiv.width(),
        minX = position.left,
        maxX = minX + sliderWidth,
        tickSize = sliderWidth / range;

      var finalMidPosition = off.left - 53 + Math.round($(divs).width() / 2 - 5)

      if (finalMidPosition >= minX && finalMidPosition <= maxX) {
        var val = Math.round((finalMidPosition - minX) / tickSize); // had to add -12…
        sliderDiv.slider("value", val);
        $(".slider-value").html(val);
        $("#text1").val(val)
      }

    }
  }

  var range = 100;
  var sliderDiv = $('#ratingBar');

  sliderDiv.slider({
    min: 0,
    max: range,
  });

  var divs = '.itemContainer'
  $(divs).draggable({
    containment: "#containment",
    cursor: 'move',
    snap: '#ratingBar',
    snapMode: 'outer',
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      findPosition("drag", ui.offset);
    },
    revert: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      };
      return !event;
    }
  });
  var position = sliderDiv.position(),
    sliderWidth = sliderDiv.width(),
    minX = position.left,
    maxX = minX + sliderWidth,
    tickSize = sliderWidth / range;
  $('#ratingBar').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: findPosition,
    over: function(e, ui) {
      $("#text1").addClass("hover");
      findPosition("in", ui.offset);
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
      $("#text1").removeClass("hover");
      findPosition("out", ui.offset);
      $("#text1").val($(".item1 .slider-value").html());
    }
  });
  $(".slider-value").html(sliderDiv.slider('value'));
}
```

This allows an intercept upon `touch`. Also, `over` only triggers once and does not continue to update throughout the `drag`. So I set a flag to indicate when over is `true` and when it is and `drag` is happening, we want to update the values. Once dropped, we can determine what to do. If the drag is `out`, we revert the value to `0`.

Comment: Ah okay - I am impressed! Thanks a lot, really appreciate your time & effort !